# How to get base url inside controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am using CakePHP 2.6.7. I want to get the following url:

**www.mydomain.com/OrderFromReseller/82BC1562-22F9-4326-8B4B-370129710E8C**

I try as:

```
$resellerURL = $this->webroot . 'OrderFromReseller/' . $this->request->data['Reseller']['api_key'];
```

But when I echo the value of `$resellerURL` it echos `http://orderfromreseller/82BC1562-22F9-4326-8B4B-370129710E8C`.

Is there any alternative of `$this->webroot` to get base url properly inside cakephp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `Router::url()` to get the full URL. For example to get the full web address for the homepage:-

```
Router::url('/', true);
```

You can pass any router array as the first parameter to get the full URL as long as you pass `true` as the second parameter. For example:-

```
$url = Router::url(
    ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'test'],
    true
);
```

Answer (score 3):

It work for me in cakephp 3.5 please follow the below code

1) add this code in the top of the controller below `namespace App\Controller;`

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
```

2) `$baseUrl = Router::url('/', true);`

This is the best and simple way to get the base url in cakephp 3+